# Android Parse SDK issue

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse to store my data and do a lot of queries while using my program.
The issue is that after about +/-20 similar queries, parse findInBackground() or getFirstInBackground() doesn't return a callback and app stuck at that possition.

My query code:

```
ParseQuery<OptionCodeDTO> mQuery;
    mQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(OptionCodeDTO.class);
    mQuery.whereEqualTo("code", prCode);
    mQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<OptionCodeDTO>() {
        @Override
        public void done(OptionCodeDTO optionCodeDTO, ParseException e) {
            if (isVisible()) {
                if (e == null) {
                    OptionCode opCode = new OptionCode(optionCodeDTO);
                    mCodes.push(opCode);
                    printCodes();
                    prDescrLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prDescProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mPRLable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    if (e.getCode() == ParseException.CONNECTION_FAILED) {
                        mPrDescr.setText(R.string.dtc_lookup_check_network);
                    } else if (e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                        mPrDescr.setText(R.string.pr_lookup_code_not_found);
                    } else {
                        mPrDescr.setText(R.string.dtc_lookup_other_problems);
                    }
                    prDescrLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prDescProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: How fast are you running the queries? There's a burst limit of 30 requests/second unless you've upgraded your plan.

Comment: By Parse analytics Performance we do not reach even 2 requests/second

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your app ANRs (application not responding) because of something from UI thread that relies on background threads, that is incorrect architecture.

Probably you have to optimize your app's interaction with Parse. Generally it is a bad practice to make lots of `saveInBackground`, for example from inside a loop. You can add objects, those need to be saved, to a list and then use `ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(objectList)`

Also an idea to optimize is to use local storage - android's built in SQLite. For example if your app relies on something being saved to Parse, the logic is like this:

1. When saving object first you save to local DB and run a saveInBackground method.
2. When fetching objects you first fetch from your local DB and then run a getInBackground method, which inside a callback persists the information to your local DB.

This way you will make your app usable without internet connection.